# Characterization of ω-cover by co-zero sets.

Tags: general-topology

In a Tychonoff space X if each ω-cover contains a refinement consists of co-zero sets which is again a ω-cover?

Comment: This question should be made more self-contained by defining the uncommon term "$\omega$-cover" used within. Also, it may be a language issue, but I'm not entirely clear what the question is.  Are you asking whether every $\omega$-cover of a Tychonoff space has a refinement of co-zero sets which is also an $\omega$-cover? Or something else?

Answer (score 2):

Of course:

For each finite set $F$ of $X$ there is some $U(F) \in \mathcal{U}$ with $F \subseteq U(F)$. As $X$ is Tychonoff, there is a cozero set $O(F)$ such that $F \subseteq O(F) \subseteq U(F)$ (e.g. cozero sets are closed under finite unions).
Then $\{O(F) : F\in [X]^{<\omega}\}$ is the required refinement and an $\omega$-cover by construction.

Comment: Let U and V be two co-zero sets by two different real valued continuous functions f and g. Then how union of U and V becomes a co-zero set again?

Comment: @Upasana try the dual: the intersection of two zerosets. There $f^2+g^2$ works.

Comment: Ok. But whether |f|+|g| will do the work for union case as union of f^{-1}(R\{0}) and g^{-}(R\{0})=(|f|+|g|)^{-1}(R\{0})

Comment: @Upasana that will probably also work. The sum is only $0$ outside the union.

Comment: As X is Tychonoff so there is a co-zero set $O$ such that $O \subset U(F).$  As  co-zero sets are closed under finite unions so there is another co-zero set O' s.t. $F \subset O'.$ But is it necessary that $O' \subset U$ for some $U\in \mathcal{U}$?

Comment: @Upasana being Tychonoff is equivalent to the fact that the cozero sets form a base. So for every $x \in F$ there is some cozero set $O_x$ with $x \in O_x \subseteq U(F)$. The $O(F)$ can then be the finite union of the $O_x, x \in F$.

Comment: @Upasana maybe you should have read more about zerosets, cozero sets etc. before reading papers like that. The authors assume all their readers already know such things by heart. A lot of topology papers basically assume you've read all of Engelking already. Or Arhangel'skij's texts etc.